# Outlook Sender mail issue

Tags: python, numpy, automation, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to get an email body on basis of a particular sender name from the outlook inbox by using the win32.com client. However, it only return the COMObject Restrict
Here my code.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import numpy as np


outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messagess = folder.Items

messages = messagess.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'Vivek.Kumar@xxx.com'")
print(messages)
arr=[]
for m in messages:
    arr=m.Body
    print(arr)
```

Comment: So what is your question? Why `print(messages)` prints "COMObject"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko..yes

Answer (score 0):

The [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) method from the Outlook object model returns a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter (an instance of the `Items` class) which is a COM object under the hood. You may try to use methods and properties of the `Items` class in the code to make sure the result is valid.

You can read more about that method in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.

Comment: Do you have any sample code related to restrict method else any other approach to get the proper result.

Comment: Most probably you get the right object returned from the `Restrict` method, you just need to try using its methods and properties, for example, you may check the `Count` property. As an alternative method you may consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the Items class.

Comment: Take a look at the [Advanced search in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) as an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` deals with scalar (string, integer, boolean, etc.) values. It does not know anything about any particular COM object - the best it can do is output the object's type name ("COMObject"). There is no way it can know anything about the `Items` Outlook object. It is your responsibility to maker sense of it by actually looping through the collection and printing values that make sense in your particular case.